# Firebase Phone Auth Blocked

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am testing Firebase SMS authentication on my android app on release mode. So, after few succesful authentications, I started getting the error:

> we have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later

I deleted the affected user but still not working. Then, I contacted Firebase support and that's what they said:

> There's a limit of 5 SMS per phone number per 4 hour

Now I am struggling how to test my app before making it live for real users.

I need to test receiving SMS instead of using whitelisted phone numbers. The reason is that I have a bug on release mode which requires many testings to be fixed. Please I need some help!

Comment: Why can't you use a whitelisted phone number to test your fix?

Comment: Thanks for info about 5 SMS per 4 hour, they should documented it.